# CopyOnWriteArrayList remove logic

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, thread-safety

In each thread i want run this sort of code
Initialize the list

```
 final int initialSize = 2000;
        final Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread creationThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < initialSize; j++) {
                    list.add(rand.nextInt(10000));
                }
            }
        });
        creationThread.start();
        creationThread.join();
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        final int threadElemAmount = initialSize / numberOfThreads;
```

Creating threads for removing

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        threads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < threadElemAmount; j++) {
                        list.remove((int) (list.size() - 1));
                }
            }
        }));
    }
```

but I'm getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` read-write problem. How avoid this?

Comment: What is the need of casting ?

Comment: Why you use the loop but don't use the variable i?

Comment: @Rehman hm, couldn't understand you.

Comment: Use iterator instead. What happens is that your list shrinks in one thread, but other threads continue to run on the whole length.

Comment: What's threadElemAmount give more details, the code not clear

Comment: @MarounMaroun I know what happens, but iterator can't solve this problem, cause we have a spase between list.size() call and list.remove() call

Comment: @Abdelhak ok, I will add this, right now

Comment: Can you give a little more context? A different data structure like a queue may be more appropriate. I don't think there is an easy way to do what you want with a COWAL.

Comment: @assylias I can use just this collection

Comment: you can use "synchronized" to avoid concurrent access to the list.

Comment: @Aracurunir Could I avoid external "synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be sure that your remove operation succeeds, then synchronize your code by the list, like:

```
public void run() {
    for (int j = 0; j < threadElemAmount; j++) {
        synchronized (list) {
            list.remove((int) (list.size() - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Also reassure that you are synchronizing by the same list instance.

The issue is caused by the fact, that this line:

```
list.remove((int) (list.size() - 1));
```

Is processed like this:

```
1: int tempVal = list.size() - 1;
2: list.remove(tempVal);
```

In your case, thread A was performing line 1, yielding execution context to thread B, which performed 1 and 2, and then thread A was throwing an exception.

Comment: Not only that, JAVA API explicitly states that "If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
Thus even if you would be removing the element at position 0, you must synchronize the access to ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this possible solution, but is there only way to solve this? Cause I have already use thread-safe CopyOnWriteArrayList.java. Just external synchronize?

Comment: @Palo, have you read the title of the question? He is using `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which allows concurrent modifications.

Comment: @Palo I'm not using ArrayList watch one more time pls

Comment: Sorry, thanks. Please paste all relevant parts of the code then. In your code sample the type of the variable list cannot be inferred. But as @user3707125 explained, your access still needs to be synchronized. Removing the first element instead of the last one seems to be equally (in)efficient way, and that could solve your task without synchronization.Is CopyOnWriteArrayList a requirement for you? Can't you just use a synchronized ArrayList instead? It would be more efficient...